# A template declaration cannot appear at block scope

Tags: c++, vector, codeblocks

I'm learning Lipmann and I'm only studying. I'm trying here to write a code that will return a minimal element in a vector. When I compile my code in Codeblocks, it says: "A template declaration cannot appear at block scope". Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    template <class elemType>
    elemType save;
    elemType min (const std::vector<elemType> &vec) {
      std::vector<elemType>::iterator it = vec.begin(), end_it = vec.end();
      std::vector<elemType>::iterator iter = std::next(it, 1);
      for ( ; it != end_it; it++ ) {
        if ( *it < *(it + 1) ) {
          save = *it;
        }
        if (save < *it) {
          save = *it;
        }
      }
    };

    int massiv[10] = {35, 66, 98, 15, 32, 41, 24, 90, 55, 100};
    std::vector<int> vec_train(massiv,massiv+10);


    min(vec_train);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, you can just use `std::min_element`.

Comment: I think the point here is that OP was trying to understand how to implement a function template like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot define template inside a function, and `main` is a function. You need to define your `min` function template outside of main, before it.

You have several other problems in your code. The

```
template <class elemType>
```

must appear immediately before the function definition. Putting

```
elemType save;
```

between them is not correct syntax.

Another problem is your algorithm for selecting the min value in a vector. Why do you have this

```
if (*save < *(it + 1) ) { save = *it; }
```

and this

```
if (*save < *it ) { save = *it; }
```

at the same time?

Here's what you probably want:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class elemType>
const elemType& min(const std::vector<elemType>& vec) {
  typename std::vector<elemType>::const_iterator
    select = vec.begin(),
    it = std::next(select),
    end = vec.end();
  for ( ; it != end; ++it ) {
    if ( *it < *select ) select = it;
  }
  return *select;
};

int main() {
  int massiv[10] = {35, 66, 98, 15, 32, 41, 24, 90, 55, 100};
  std::vector<int> vec_train(massiv,massiv+10);

  std::cout << min(vec_train) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

If you need to handle empty vectors, you could add

```
if (!vec.size()) throw std::length_error("empty vector passed to min");
```

at the beginning of the function, or return an iterator instead of element reference, as `end()` is well defined even for empty vectors.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Done :) Yes, thats exactly what i wanted. Your answer is great, thank you for your attention :)

Comment: This code has *many* compilation errors and does not consider the case of an empty vector. `min` should return an iterator, not an element, or assert that the vector is not empty. Of course, in real code, one would just use `std::min_element`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Ok, I fixed the errors. OP was returning vector element by value in his question, so I did the next closest thing that doesn't copy `elemType`.

Comment: @SU3: Compiles now. I think it's still a poorly designed interface for a function because you practically cannot implement it without invoking undefined behaviour for empty vectors.